# Looping through rows in table to reset forms in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have a table that consists of 4 columns that contain forms. Two text boxes and two calendar widgets. I am trying to add a fifth column(reset), which will give the user the chance to reset any information on the row. I was able to reset, but, there's a bug. If I change a few columns and click the reset on my desired row it will reset the whole table. How can I reset one row, without it affecting the rest?

I found this example on w3schools.com, where it will reset both forms as well.

```html
<html>
<body>

<p>Enter some text in the fields below, then press the "Reset form" button to reset the form.</p>

<form id="myForm">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Reset form">
</form>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

So, I tried fiddling with the script so only the first name form would reset and not the last name. This isn't working, how can I accomplish this? Thanks

```html
<html>
<body>

<p>Enter some text in the fields below, then press the "Reset form" button to reset the form.</p>

<form>
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="Marie" id="myForm"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Reset form">
</form>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").value= ' ';
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `reset` function belongs to `form` element. `input` elements have `value` property which you can set to empty value :`document.getElementById("myForm").value = "";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reset method only works on the entire form. If you want to clear just one input you need to clear his value.

**See the code below:**

```html
<html>
<body>

<p>Enter some text in the fields below, then press the "Reset form" button to reset the form.</p>

<form>
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname" id="myForm"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Reset form">
</form>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").value='';
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I think this solution will only work if the form is blank at default how can we achieve the same thing if the forms default has a value without creating two form tags?

Comment: I don't really see what you want now. I think I need more details to understand what you want to do.

Comment: I just edited my question, I hope this clears everything up! So I set the default First name to "Marie", so when I reset anytime I make changes I want to reset back to "Marie"

Comment: Ok. So you could do it by replacing the empty value ' ' by 'Marie' in the script like this :`document.getElementById("myForm").value='Marie'`. Tell me if it works for you.